# Auto layout with navigation bar and container view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar

so, I'm pretty sure I have my auto layout constraints set up correctly... And I have my view controller embedded in a navigation controller. I put all of the things inside of a uiview that's constrained to the 4 sides of the phone (including the bottom of the navigation bar) but this is happening.

I have the picture constrained to the vertical center of the view, and at a 1:3 ratio to it's height. the buttons are constrained on the sides

the problem is that (as you can see by the button borders and the button text being off centered) everything seems to be larger than it should be and is causing an overlap, when the buttons are supposed to be flush against the bottom and top of the image view, but instead overflow on top of it (again, shown by the button borders)

[image: help me]

[image: some more help]

[image: and some more here]

Comment: Add your code and what have you tried yet?

Comment: define what is your actual problem???

Comment: Please add screenshot of how you have applied constraints to each and every object from storyboard to understand your question perfectly.

Comment: Well, the problem is that (as you can see by the button borders and the button text being off centered) everything seems to be larger than it should be and is causing an overlap, when the buttons are supposed to be flush against the bottom and top of the image view, but instead overflow on top of it (again, shown by the button borders)

Answer (score 0):

ah, I'm just an idiot. Image View wasn't clipping subviews. Auto Layout's working just fine! Thanks. My b.